# Detecting the user location

Tags: ip

I visit a page with my firefox browser and i see this message "You appear to be outside the United States or its territories.". Also on http://www.fmylife.com/ they appear to detect the state/province the user is in. How do i do this? (I cant decide if this should be on SO for programming or here bc of networking/servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So geolocation.

The most common is to use [MaxMind](http://maxmind.com). You can find static copies of geo data around the internet, however they get out of date *very* quickly.

There are other providers, however MaxMind are the one database that ISP's will usually go to and ensure is correct, also google, however they don't make their data public.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to [IP Geolocation](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/IP_geolocation)

How are you wanting to implement it, within an application you're developing?